# How to connect Python to Node.js?

Tags: javascript, python, variables, flask

I want to send to python a node.js variable, modify it with python and resend it to node.js, that is an example of my codes:
Python

```
def change_input(variable):
    variable*=5
    #now send variable to node.js
```

Now the js code:

```
var variable=prompt("enter the variable");
#after the code was sended to thd python code, modified and resend:
document.write(variable)
```

How to circulates the variables between python and javascript?

Comment: Start a web server with node.js express and make python request the server to get this variable and then send it back. Other than that you'd have to play around with interprocess communication. Read up on sockets and pipes

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it, by spawning a child python process from within node.

test.js:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const p = spawn('python', ['yourscript.py', '1']);

p.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
```

yourscript.py

```
import sys

def change_var(x):
    print('hello from python: {:d}'.format(int(x) + 2))

change_var(sys.argv[1])
```

output of running `node ./test.js`:

```
stdout: hello from python: 4
```

directory layout

```
➜  test tree
.
├── test.js
└── yourscript.py

0 directories, 2 files
```

related:

- https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/child_process.html
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html
- [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python/92395#92395)

Comment: @WaaberiIbrahim updated with some extra info. hope it helps.